# Change of status flag with Codeigniter jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am working on a project where i want my employees to send task report to me within deadline. When he/she starts working on a task, it will show a yellow flag.

1. when he/she finishes task within the deadline and sends report to the manager, yellow turns into green
2. If he/she fails to complete task within deadline, it will show red flag and can't submit his/her task unless and until we allow more extensions for this job to be done...

I want to develop a system like this with codeigniter and how do i establish jquery in codeigniter to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Nope.. Actually, i need to know the way / initial approach to solve this problem..